# Deploying multiple Go applications using Nginx

Tags: nginx, go, web-deployment

The are two web applications (websites) written on Go. One is turalasgar.pro (here I am using Go built-in server). Another is engossip.com (for now it displays the same ip as former). I have a vps. I know I should use Nginx, but have no idea how? I have heard of Caddy. Please, I need only nginx server, not Caddy. What I need is run two (or more) applications by using my same vps. How should I configure Nginx configuration? Whether by listening to different ports or to the same port. Practical advices and examples highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called reverse proxy. Each application uses it's own port to listen. And then you just point to them in nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name turalasgar.pro;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        ...
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name engossip.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Shall I write the same server ip to both domain? And if so then Nginx will realize which domain comes from and accordingly it will map?

Comment: And when I copy the code you have given I got this error.

`Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Comment: Both DNS must have the same IP. Requests that came to the turalasgar.pro will go to http://localhost:8080. Requests that came to the engossip.com will go to http://localhost:8081.

Comment: @tural-Əsgərov maybe you forgot to replace `...` with the actual config values? You can find the docs [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well is really easy.

follow this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-martini-to-serve-go-applications-behind-an-nginx-server-on-ubuntu

After you achieved one application working with martini+nginx just add another `server` block for the other app.

In case you need more information about server blocks:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions I tried but didn't work for me

> https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0

```
server {
listen       ...;
...
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;
}

location /mail {
    rewrite ^/mail(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8282;
}
...
```

}